# PHP PEAR Crypt_CBC implementation in java

Tags: java, php, encryption, pear, blowfish

I am trying to encrypt a value using the BLOWFISH cipher. The implementation must be in java and having the same result as the php version:

```
require_once('/usr/share/php/Crypt/CBC.php');
....
$cipher = new Crypt_CBC($key, 'BLOWFISH');
$encryptedPassword = $cipher->encrypt($valueToEncrypt);
echo "ENCODED STRING: " . $encryptedPassword;
$encodedPassword = base64_encode($encryptedPassword);
echo "ENCRYPTED STRING: " . $encodedPassword;
```

I tried something like this, but I cannot manage to get something even remotely similar:

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
String IV = "RandomIV";
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec
    , new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes())
);
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
String encoded =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
```

Any helping idea is appreciated

Comment: can you add output of your php and java program, for testing purpose?

Comment: for "test12" the value should be something similar, if not equal to "UmFuZG9tSVZpEXCgXjR0cC256TF53Q57" / UmFuZG9tSVYlqdk15MVbSgmLAwKSNGHK / 
UmFuZG9tSVbDA3kPFVpPvv6MQ2LmK8UG (php); In java< i get "6riMPoAB9mZ1TrDOsOaAiw=="

Comment: The PHP code prepends the IV to the ciphertext. But even after stripping that off the result is still different. I'd still want a complete set of input/output data to analyze, including iv, key, input, and output.

Comment: Pay attention to 2 points: 1. The `Crypt_CBC`-constructor generates a hash from the passed key as follows: First, a MD5-Hash is created from the key. If the length of that hash is smaller than specified in the `keysize`-property (56 Byte), a MD5-hash of the already hashed value is created and appended. This procedure is repeated until the length of the hash is >= 56 Byte. The first 56 Byte are used as key. 2. The `Crypt_CBC-encrypt`-method returns a string by concatenating the value of the `header_spec`-property (default-value: `RandomIV`), the (randomly generated) IV and the encrypted data.